# Android Studio Gradle dont want to sync

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is first time using Android Studio. and found problem said that

Build file 'C:\Users\anauf\AndroidStudioProjects\Modul1_Kel20_1\build.gradle' line: 8

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Modul1_Kel20_1'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84bX4.jpg)

i've delete and re download the gradle, but the erorr still remain. anyone can help me please?

Comment: Hello! Can you copy/paste here your build.gradle information about androidx related dependencys?

Comment: dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your Gradle version is 3.*.* or higher before using **"implementation"**

Open the project level Gradle file

```
dependencies{
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
}
```

Open the 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file and set the **distributionUrl:**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

or any latest version. And finally Sync the project.